# not build desktop windows in the flutter-android studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, desktop

I can build(run) flutter desktop in the vs code but can not build (run)flutter desktop in the android studio 4.2

[image]

Comment: have you enable windows config?

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to include your code and error messages as **text** rather than as a screenshot?  It's policy here not to to use images for this purpose, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why.  You're most likely to get an answer if you include a full [mcve] with that shows us how to recreate the problem.  See: [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Add existing flutter app to windows desktop support with following statement;

```
 flutter create --platforms=windows
```